# Limitations of variables in python

Tags: python, class, variables, python-3.x, data-structures

I realize this may be a bit broad, and thought this was an interesting question that I haven't really seen an answer to.  It may be hidden in the python documentation somewhere, but as I'm new to python haven't gone through all of it yet.

So.. are there any general rules of things that we cannot set to be variables? Everything in python is an object and we can use variables for the typical standard usage of storing strings, integers, aliasing variables, lists, calling references to classes, etc and if we're clever even something along the lines as the below that I can think of off the top of my head, wherever this may be useful

```
var = lambda: some_function()
```

storing comparison operators to clean code up such as:

```
var = some_value < some_value ...
```

So, that being said I've never come across anything that I couldn't store as a variable if I really wanted to, and was wondering if there really are any limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really store *expressions and statements* as objects in Python.

Sure, you can wrap an expression in a `lambda`, and you can wrap a series of statements in a code object or callable, but you can't easily manipulate them.  For instance, changing all instances of addition to multiplication is not readily possible.

To some extent, this can be worked around with the `ast` module, which provides for parsing Python code into abstract syntax trees.  You can then manipulate the trees, instead of the code itself, and pass it to `compile()` to turn it back into a code object.

However, this is a form of indirection, compensating for a feature Python itself lacks.  `ast` can't really compare to the anything-goes flexibility of (say) Lisp macros.

Comment: By new I meant less than half a year of experience I just haven't started looking into data structures or algorithms or how languages generally work, just been trying to learn the fundamentals first. I understood the and haven;t even heard of that module I'll have to take a look at it

Comment: @jakekimds: If you can spot anything that needs fixing, feel free to suggest an edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can't store syntactical constructs in a variable. For example, you can't do

```
command = break

while condition:
    if other_condition:
        command
```

or

```
operator = +
three = 1 operator 2
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), the right hand side of an assignment statement can be an 'expression list' or a 'yield expression'. An expression list is a comma-separated list of one or more expressions. You need to follow this through several more tokens to come up with anything concrete, but ultimately you can find that an 'expression' is any number of objects (literals or variable names, or the result of applying a unary operator such as `not`, `~` or `-` to a nested expression_list) chained together by any binary operator (such as the arithmetic, comparison or bitwise operators, or logical `and` and `or`) or the ternary `a if condition else b`.

You can also note in other parts of the language reference that an 'expression' is exactly something you can use as an argument to a function, or as the first part (before the `for`) of a list comprehension or generator expression.

This *is* a fairly broad definition - in fact, it amounts to "anything Python resolves to an object". But it does leave out a few things - for example, you can't directly store the less-than operator `<` in a variable, since it isn't a valid expression by itself (it has to be between two other expressions) and you have to put it in a function that uses it instead. Similarly, most of the Python [keywords](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) aren't expressions (the exceptions are True, False and None, which are all canonical names for certain objects).

Note especially that functions are also objects, and hence the name of a function (without calling it) is a valid expression. This means that your example:

```
var = lambda: some_function()
```

can be written as:

```
var = some_function
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a variable is something which can vary, or change. In its broadest sense, a variable is no more than a way of referring to a location in memory in your given program. Another way to think of a variable is as a container to place your information in.

Unlike popular strongly typed languages,  variable declaration in Python is not required. You can place pretty much anything in a variable so long as you can come up with a name for it. Furthermore, in addition to the value of a variable in Python being capable of changing, the type often can as well.

**To address your question**, I would say the limitations on a variable in Python relate only to a few basic necessary attributes:

A name

A scope

A value

*(Usually)* a type

As a result, things like operators (`+` or `*` for instance) cannot be stored in a variable as they do not meet these basic requirements, and in general you cannot store *[expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html)* themselves as variables (unless you're wrapping them in a lambda expression).

---

As mentioned by [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1340389/kevin), it's also worth noting that it is possible to *sort of*  store an operator in a variable using the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html) , however even doing so you cannot perform the kinds of manipulations that a variable is otherwise subject to as really you are just making a value assignment. An example of the `operator` module:

```
import operator
operations = {"+": operator.add,
              "-": operator.sub,}

operator_variable_string= input('Give me an operand:')
operator_function = operations[operator_variable_string]
result = operator_function(8, 4)
```

Comment: You can *sort of* store an operator in a variable (see the `operator` module).  But you can't perform the kinds of manipulations that would otherwise imply.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, that's worth noting. Mind if I edit it in and reference you?

Comment: In a way, you can actually store expressions: `x = lambda: <expression>`.